# What is wrong with my header setup

Tags: c++

What is wrong with my setup with DWORD and LPCTSTR?

```
class myApp : public CApplication
{
public:
    unsigned int DWORD;
    const char *LPCTSTR;


    myApp( CApplication::ApplicationByteAware theAppByte = CApplication::AB_SINGLEBYTE );
    virtual ~myApp( void );

    DWORD IsProcessRunning(LPCTSTR procname);
    bool TerminateProcess(LPCTSTR procname);
}
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? Is this the entire header file? What does the source file look like? In short, there isn't enough information here to help you very well.

Comment: The variable names that you use are already names of types declared somewhere in `<windows.h>`. Also, don't forget the `;` after your class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `DWORD` and `LPCTSTR` as member variables but trying to use them as types. What you want to do instead is

```
// declare the typedefs here
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef const char *LPCTSTR;

class myApp : public CApplication
{
public:

    myApp( CApplication::ApplicationByteAware theAppByte = CApplication::AB_SINGLEBYTE );
    virtual ~myApp( void );

    // then you can use them here    
    DWORD IsProcessRunning(LPCTSTR procname);
    bool TerminateProcess(LPCTSTR procname);
};
```

Comment: No actually he should include <windows.h> that define those typedefs. Otherwise double definition conflicts will arise if he ever includes <windows.h> in the same translation.

Answer (score 5):

You've declared DWORD as a variable name (member name) and then tried to specify it as a return type for IsProcessRunning.  The latter should return unsigned int instead.  Use a typedef if you want to alias a type name.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Windows program will include `<windows.h>` which in turn includes other files which define these widely used macros.

Comment: DWORD and LPCTSTR are not macros. They are typedefs. Also see KQ's answer.